# Group Column by Day- DAX

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I have this Table A:

| ITEM | DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 04.11.2021 13:38:51 | 1 |
| A | 04.11.2021 08:07:44 | 1 |
| A | 04.11.2021 08:07:42 | 1 |
| A | 04.11.2021 13:53:28 | 1 |
| B | 22.10.2021 21:14:19 | 1 |
| B | 22.10.2021 16:18:09 | 1 |
| B | 22.10.2021 18:15:11 | 1 |
| C | 06.11.2021 22:08:46 | 1 |

And i would like to Group and count the item by Date (no time) like this:
|ITEM|DATE|COUNT|
|----|----|-----|
|A|04.11.2021 |4|
|B|22.10.2021 |3|
|C|06.11.2021 |1|

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```sql
Select
    [Item],
    DateValue([Date]) As ItemDate,
    Sum([Count])
From
    [Table A]
Group By
    [Item],
    DateValue([Date]) As ItemDate
```

Answer (score 0):

**method1:**

Change the **DATE** format to yyyy-mm-dd or each other Date format.
Then change in Values **DATE** from **Don't summarize** to **Earliest or Lastest**.
This method will change the **DATE** format from **Datetime** to **Date** and will also change in other Visuals formats. If you used **Date** base on datetime in other visuals, the problem is happened.
[image]

**method2:**

Create a **new column(`_date = 'Table A'[DATE].[Date]`)** or **new measure(`_date= max('Table A'[DATE].[Date])`)**, and use it instead of **DATE** in the visual.

You can also use `_COUNT=COUNT('Table A'[DATE])` instead of **COUNT**.